# SCNPhysicsHingeJoint not rotating if shape is complex

Tags: ios8, scenekit

I'd found a strange behaviour in joint rotation of collada object in SceneKit.

Imagine, I use this code for make rotating desk (complex form desk made in cheeta3d):

```
SCNScene *heroScene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"scene.dae"];
b = [heroScene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"desk" recursively:YES];
b.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody dynamicBody];
b.physicsBody.physicsShape=[SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithNode:b options:@{SCNPhysicsShapeTypeKey:SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron,SCNPhysicsShapeKeepAsCompoundKey:@YES}]; //**HERE we need YES only, if NO it is not rotating**!
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:b];
SCNPhysicsHingeJoint *joint = [SCNPhysicsHingeJoint jointWithBody:b.physicsBody axis:SCNVector3Make(0,1,0) anchor:SCNVector3Make(0,5,0)];
[scene.physicsWorld addBehavior:joint];
```

Look at comment //**HERE we need YES only, if NO it is not rotating**!

I tested all cases, all joints. SCNPhysicsShapeKeepAsCompoundKey must be YES although I think it is not so important here.

Why is it?

Answer (score 1):

SCNPhysicsShapeKeepAsCompoundKey defaults to YES.  From what I can tell that turns off the " flattenedCone " version of the physics object.  Most likely you have something in your model that is keeping it from rotating when the hinge joint attaches to only one section of the model instead of the whole thing.

Comment: it is interesting, but in iOs9.new (now, after a year since the question) no objects rotating , independently from YES or NO here :-( can't find why. Do not want to remake models

Comment: ah, interesting: apple says: "This shape type [SCNPhysicsShapeTypeKey:SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron] may only be used for static physics bodies." So before rotating was just a bug